# Why render is not triggered even the props changed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been using react+redux quite while, but could you any one help me the following case, on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ron-liu/pen/qVpGvp?editors=1111):

```
const {createStore } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;

const store = createStore((state={name: 'ron'}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'changeName': return {name: action.name};
    default: return state
  }
})

const Person = props => {
  const {name, dispatch} = props
  console.log(`rendering Person due to name changed to ${name}`)
  return (
    <div>
      <p> My name is {name} </p> 
      <button onClick={ () => dispatch({type: 'changeName', name: 'ron'}) } > Change to Ron </button>
      <button onClick={ () => dispatch({type: 'changeName', name: 'john'}) } > Change to John</button>
    </div>  
  )
}

const App = connect(state=>state)(Person)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It is simple react app, but I cannot explain:

1. Initialise redux store with one reducer, and its initValue is `{name: 'ron'}`
2. Click `Change to ron` button, it will dispatch `{type: 'changeName', name: 'ron'}`
3. When the reducer get this action, it will generate an brand new state `{name: 'ron'}`, though the value is same as the original state, but they are different identity and should be the different ones.
4. The functional component should be re-rendered if the props changed even though the values are the same. So I suppose the render function will be called, and console should output `rendering Person due to...`. However, it is not happening.

I am wondering why react functional component refuse to render again when the props identity are changed (though the values are the same)

Comment: React checks for change in value and updates the virtual DOM.  If there is no change in data (even though identity has been changed), then no update to virtual DOM and there won't be a re-render

Comment: You have pure component, no state, no side-effects therefore it will not re-render if there is no changes in values. If you want it to re-render you should create a ES6 class style component.

Comment: @JayabalajiJ but a component should re-render. Right? Although there won't be any DOM insertions. It should at least log the statement as stated in question

Comment: @hidden_4003 I think functional component is NOT pure component, I tried to use normal stateful component, still the same behavior.

Comment: @Ron functional component's ain't pure and that's why they are fast. The are avoided all checks to make them fast. That is pretty weird, I've almost tried to find for 4-5 hours. I feel there is some optimisation in mapStateToProps of connect but I couldn't find any. I've starred the question so that I'm able to get answer when someone gives it.

Comment: @Ron I did not say that any functional component is pure but your implementation is, and it does behave like a pure one as render is not executed if props are the same.

Comment: @hidden_4003 How this is a pure component where he hasn't use any of `PureComponent`, recompose's `pure` or manually used `shouldComponentUpdate`. Also, I tried that out, the redux store is not mutating either. there is a brand new state coming from redux which should rerender the Person component

Comment: @AjayGaur Component is pure if it is guaranteed to return the same result given the same props and state. What you mentioned is merely a performance optimization and it looks like React treats functional components same as PureComponent.

Comment: No react doesn't treat functional components as pure components. I'm pretty much sure about it because they are to optimise the process and reduce the time lag. They won't implement `pure` implicitely

Comment: @AjayGaur It is the connect that does it.https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/connect.js#L21 "The resulting final props selector is called by the Connect component instance whenever
  it receives new props or store state."

Comment: @hidden_4003 but when you pass a brand new state then even shouldComponentUpdate (`shallowCompare`) will return true because it only checks the references

Comment: @AjayGaur connect() from react-redux package is a pure component so it blocks the re-render

Comment: 1. connect is not a `Component`. It is just a function
2. It takes 2 arguments which are also functions. In mapStateToProps, it does a `shallowCompare` on state

Answer (score 1):

Your `connect(state=>state)(Person)` I think it's not wrong but it's weird.

According to the documentation https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html you can separate the state and the action dispatcher, commonly naming mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

So, I propose to you this code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateName: (name) => dispatch(changeName(name)),
})

class DemoContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> My name is {this.props.user.name}</p> 
      <button onClick={ () => this.props.updateName('ron') } > Change to Ron </button>
      <button onClick={ () => this.props.updateName('john') } > Change to John</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
const Demo = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DemoContainer)

export default Demo
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = { name: 'John'}

const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_NAME":
      return {
        name: action.name
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default user
```

My action:

```
export const changeName = ( name ) => ({
  type: "CHANGE_NAME",
  name,
})
```

You can check all my code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tchqrg

I have a class for the component but you can also use a functional component with connect like you do.